# jQuery - How to prevent Weather API from slowing down my website?

Tags: jquery, weather-api

I recently added a weather forecast to my website. The script is as follows:

After the footer:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="../js/weather.js"></script>
```

The jQuery:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {

$.ajax({
type: 'GET',
url: "http://api.worldweatheronline.com/free/v1/weather.ashx?q=Gstaad&format=json&num_of_days=5&key=key",
async: false,
contentType: "application/json",
dataType: 'jsonp',
success: function (response) {
    var weather = response.data.weather;
    var weekdays = ["SUN", "MON", "TUES", "WED", "THU", "FRI", "SAT"];
    var ids = ['#first_', '#second_', '#third_', '#fourth_', '#fifth_'];
    for (var i = 0; i < weather.length; i++) {    

        $(ids[i]+"img").attr('src', "http://swissskiresorts.com/wp-content/themes/swiss-ski-resorts/images/day/"+weather[i].weatherCode+".png");
        $(ids[i]+"img").attr('title', weather[i].weatherDesc[0].value);
        $(ids[i]+"min").text(weather[i].tempMinC);
        $(ids[i]+"max").text(weather[i].tempMaxC);

        if(i > 0)
            {                           
        var d = new Date(weather[i].date);
        $(ids[i]+"day").text(weekdays[d.getDay()]);
            }
            }
                console.dir(response);
            },
            error: function (e) {
                console.log(e.message);
        }

}); });
```

I noticed that my site takes significantly longer to load.

Is there anything that I can do speed things up?  Maybe delay the weather forecast

Comment: Part of the problem is that `async: false`. By doing that you're locking up the screen. Putting async to false is just a really, really bad idea. There's always a better way.

Comment: Hi thanks for the tip!  Should I set async to true?

Comment: Yes, or just delete that property. By default it is true. However, to be sure, I'd need to see what's in the loop.

Comment: Dear Jonathan, I have updated the snippet.  Do you believe it can be improved?  Did I mess something up ? :-(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try removing `async:false`.

Ajax is designed to be asynchronous. Putting `async:false` is a bad idea, and there's always a better way.

Having `async:false` makes everything, even your GUI update, wait on completion of the task. That's not what you want.

Here's a pretty good article about it: http://javascript.about.com/od/ajax/a/ajaxasyn.htm

Answer (score 0):

"async:true" will allow other scripts to run while your ajax request is being treated.
This way your ajax request will not be blocking the page load anymore.